# Approach for one class to safely refer to another, with both having unknown lifetimes

Tags: c++, c++11

It is not always possible to simplify program design by strictly managing the lifetimes of objects. If two objects have unpredictable lifetimes, but one of them needs to refer to the other, a simple pointer or reference is a segmentation fault waiting to happen.

The approach that I tried first was to have both objects contain a pointer to the other, and code in the destructors of both objects that would set the other object's pointer to null:

```
#include <iostream>

class Manager;

class Tracked
{
public:
    ~Tracked();
    void act() {std::cout << "hello world!\n";}
    void setManager(Manager *manager) {manager_ = manager;}
    void markManagerInvalid() {manager_ = nullptr;}
private:
    Manager *manager_;
};

class Manager
{
public:
    void attach(Tracked &tracked)
    {
        tracked_ = &tracked;
        tracked_->setManager(this);
    }
    void detach()
    {
        if(tracked_ != nullptr)
        {
            tracked_->markManagerInvalid();
            tracked_ = nullptr;
        }
    }
    void invoke()
    {
        if(tracked_ != nullptr)
            tracked_->act();
    }
private:
    Tracked *tracked_;
};

Tracked::~Tracked()
{
    if(manager_ != nullptr)
        manager_->detach();
}

int main()
{
    Manager manager;
    {
        Tracked tracked;
        manager.attach(tracked);
        manager.invoke(); //output: hello world!
    }//"tracked" goes out of scope: the pointer in "manager" is now invalidated.
    manager.invoke();
}
```

This works and sounds very simple but in practice it has serious drawbacks:

- There is not only tight coupling but also a circular dependency between `Tracker` and `Manager`.
- In order to have many `Manager` instances link to the same `Tracked` instance, the `Tracked` class would have to incorporate a list of `Manager` pointers to instances that are linking to it.
- The code is complex and error prone, and would get even worse with multiple instances linking to each other.

To get around this I devised a different solution: A dynamically allocated pointer to the `Tracked` instance. The pointer would be set to `nullptr` by the pointed `Tracked` instance in the insance's destructor to mark the instance as expired. The same pointer instance is shared using `std::shared_ptr` with all objects requiring safe access to the `Tracked` instance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Tracked
{
public:
    using Handle = std::shared_ptr<Tracked*>;
    Tracked() : handle_(new Tracked*(this)) { }
    ~Tracked() {*handle_ = nullptr;}
    void act() {std::cout << "hello world!\n";}
    Handle getHandle() {return handle_;}
private:
    Handle handle_;
};

class Manager
{
public:
    void attach(Tracked &tracked) {handle_ = tracked.getHandle();}
    void detach() {handle_.reset();}
    void invoke()
    {
        if(handle_ != nullptr)
        {
            if(*handle_ != nullptr)
                (*handle_)->act();
        }
    }
private:
    Tracked::Handle handle_;
};

int main()
{
    Manager a, b, c;
    {
        Tracked tracked;
        a.attach(tracked);
        b.attach(tracked);
        a.invoke(); //output: hello world!
    } //"tracked" goes out of scope: the handles in "a" and "b" are now invalidated.
    b.invoke();
    c.invoke();
}
```

I have found surprisingly little information on this, is this a known idiom or design pattern?

Edit:
At the conclusion of writing this question I realized that I could just allocate the `Tracked` object with `new` and manage the object with a `std::shared_ptr`, distributing a `std::weak_ptr` to each `Manager`. If `std::weak_ptr::lock()` would return a null shared_ptr, the `Tracked` instance would be expired.

Comment: Aye. But look at `make_shared`, it is potentialy more eficient

Comment: I can't say that this is recognized as a pattern, but it is a major use case for `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a bit of dynamic allocation `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` makes sense as they provide a solid implementation of the tracking behaviour you need.

Your original though has a nice property of not using any dynamic allocation.
If the tracking logic could be refine and made more general if might be a handy bit of library code to have around.

This is my attempt so far:

```
template <typename T>
class SafeRefTo;

template <typename T>
class Tracked : public T
{
public:
    using T::T;
    ~Tracked();
    void addReferee(SafeRefTo<T> *manager) {safeRefToThis = manager;}
    void markSafeRefInvalid() {safeRefToThis = nullptr;}
private:
    SafeRefTo<T> *safeRefToThis;
};

template <typename T>
class SafeRefTo
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    Tracked<T> makeTracked(Args... args)
    {
        Tracked<T> tracked{args...};
        attach(tracked);
        return tracked;
    }

    void attach(Tracked<T> &tracked)
    {
        tracked_ = &tracked;
        tracked_->addReferee(this);
    }
    void detach()
    {
        if(tracked_ != nullptr)
        {
            tracked_->markSafeRefInvalid();
            tracked_ = nullptr;
        }
    }
    template <typename TrackedMemFun, typename... Args>
    void invoke(TrackedMemFun fun, Args... args)
    {
        if(tracked_ != nullptr)
            (tracked_->*fun)(args...);
    }
private:
    Tracked<T> *tracked_;
};

template <typename T>
Tracked<T>::~Tracked()
{
    if(safeRefToThis != nullptr)
        safeRefToThis->detach();
}
```

Then the client code is simply:

```
#include <iostream>

class Actor
{
public:
    Actor() = default;
    Actor(std::string extraText)
    :
    extraText(extraText)
    {}

    void act(unsigned int times) {
        for(; times; --times)
        {
            std::cout << "hello world!" << extraText << "\n";
        }
    }

private:
    std::string extraText;
};

int main()
{
    SafeRefTo<Actor> manager;
    {
        auto tracked(manager.makeTracked());
        manager.invoke(&Actor::act, 1); //output: hello world!
    }//"tracked" goes out of scope: the pointer in "manager" is now invalidated.
    manager.invoke(&Actor::act, 1);
}
```